# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{dt}{\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^nt^{1/n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Q) Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{dt}{\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^nt^{1/n}}$$

I was hoping to apply Dominated convergence theorem to use  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{-n}= e^{-t}$$

but clearly I know the lower bounds but not an upper bound function which is absolutely integrable.

$$\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{-n}\geq e^{-t},t^{-1/n}\geq t^{-1} \quad\text{at least on } (1,\infty)$$

Can I find an upper bound or have to figure out the integral itself first? Thanks.

Comment: The second inequality isn't quite correct. It's only true on the interval $(0,1)$, but for the interval $(1,\infty)$ it's the other way around. You'll have to find a dominating function in order to use DCT. If not, you can try to integrate this. However, the intervals seem to suggest you want to find two dominating functions, one for each side of the domain.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. On $(0,1)$, $t^{-1/n}\leq t^{-1}$ and on $(1,\infty)$, $t^{-1/n}\geq t^{-1}$.

Comment: Good point, but my main idea still stands. Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, true. Not sure how to integrate except by integration by parts but that's not yielding a result.

Comment: I meant can you find two dominating functions?

Comment: Two dominating functions such that their product is absolutely integrable, no!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $(0,1]$, the sequence $\{t^{-1/n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing. And $\{(1+t/n)^{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing for all $t>0$, and $\{(1+t/n)^{-n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing.

Note that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1+t/2)^{2}}\dfrac{1}{t^{1/2}}dt\leq\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{t^{1/2}}dt<\infty$, so by Monotone Convergence Theorem $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1+t/n)^{n}}\dfrac{1}{t^{1/n}}dt\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}e^{-t}dt$.

Note that Monotone Convergence Theorem has the decreasing version, as long as $f_{1}\in L^{1}$, $f_{1}\geq f_{2}\geq\cdots$, then the integrals correspond to them also converge.

Now we look at the interval $[1,\infty)$. We have 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{(1+t/n)^{n}}\dfrac{1}{t^{1/n}}\leq\dfrac{1}{(1+t/n)^{n}}\leq\dfrac{1}{(1+t/2)^{2}}
\end{align*}
and $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(1+t/2)^{2}}dt<\infty$, an integrable upper bound is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $f_n=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^nt^{1/n}}$

Then $f_n(t) \to e^{-t}$ on $(0,\infty)$

Also $\forall n \geq 2$ $$(1+\frac{t}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(\frac{t}{n})^k\geq 1+\frac{t^2}{2}$$

So $$\int_0^{\infty}|f_n| \leq \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{t}}dt = \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{t}}dt+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{t}}dt=I_1+I_2$$

> $I_2 \leq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2/2+1}dt<+\infty$
>
> $I_1 \leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt$

Thus $|f_n| \leq \frac{1}{t^2/2+1}1_{[1,+\infty]}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}1_{(0,1)} \in L^1((0,\infty)$

Use D.C.T